# Excluding cmake's own distribution modules with `find_package()`

Tags: cmake, cmake-modules

Cmake includes various distribution modules (i.e., populated inside the `Modules/` directory of a cmake installation; e.g., `/usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindBoost.cmake`).

This creates challenges when developing code that includes internal libraries with names that conflict with these distribution modules, as `find_package(Xyz)` finds the distribution module (`/usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindXyz.cmake`) rather than the user module (`/home/user/opt/lib/cmake/Xyz-config.cmake`). I've tried setting `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` and `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE=ONLY`, but to no avail.

How can I force cmake to exclude its own distribution modules when evaluating `find_package()`?

Comment: Just pass `CONFIG` or `NO_MODULE` to `find_package` call. So it won't search `FindXXX.cmake` module.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Oh, perfect! Many thanks, missed that. Want to add as an answer so I can accept? Ideally, I don't want to have to change how I call find_package() as I may not have access to that (e.g., third party repository). Your comment led me to `CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_PREFER_CONFIG`, which I'm pretty sure is what I want.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Ah, very interesting, thanks! Your comments solve my frustrations and are very much appreciated! If you put them into an answer, I'll mark as accepted.

Comment: Hm, actually `Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE` variable has opposite effect: Being set to ON, it **prevents** `FindBoost.cmake` script, shipped with CMake, from searching for config script (`boost-config.cmake`). I have removed my previous comment since it was wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an **author** of the project you may find "legacy" *find* script (`FindXXX.cmake`) as non-suitable for you and prefer to use "modern" *config* script (`XXXConfig.cmake` or `config-xxx.cmake`) instead. In that case you may pass additional `CONFIG` or `NO_MODULE` option to the `find_package`:

```
find_package(Boost NO_MODULE)
```

This would prevent CMake from searching `FindBoost.cmake` script and forces it to search `BoostConfig.cmake` (or `config-boost.cmake`).

If *config* script could not be found with `NO_MODULE` or `CONFIG` option, then CMake will report an error even if corresponding *find* script exists.

Alternatively, you may set `CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_PREFER_CONFIG` variable:

```
set(CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_PREFER_CONFIG ON)
```

so CMake would check *config* script first. But if this script is missing, then CMake will try to use *find* script.

---

As the **user** of the project you may find the *config* script for some package nicer than the *find* one... but it is better to **change nothing** in this case: It could be that project you are using can work only with the *find* script, and cannot work with *config* one. (E.g. the project uses **variables**, which are created by *find* script to refer the libraries, but *config* scripts usually create IMPORTED **targets**).

Comment: Thanks; very interesting point regarding why users might not want to do this.

Comment: Note, that my answer is about selecting between *find* (`FindXXX.cmake`) and *config* (`XXXConfig.cmake`) scripts. Or, being more precise, about selecting between MODULE and CONFIG **modes** of `find_package`. My answer is NOT about selecting between several **installations** of the package. As a user of the project which requires some package, you may want CMake to find specific installation of this package instead of "default" (system) one. And CMake provides well-defined mechanisms for express your preferences. But these mechanisms are another story.